# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/core/os/UserManagerCompat

Tags: android, ionic3, cordova-plugins, android-build, build-error

I have an Ionic3 app. From last two days, it creates build successfully but App crashes while deploying to android device or emulator with the following error:

**My Exception:**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/core/os/UserManagerCompat;
   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis + 560(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:560)
   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp + 310(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:310)
   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp + 273(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:273)
   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp + 257(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:257)
   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate + 53(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:53)
   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo + 1917(ContentProvider.java:1917)
   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo + 1892(ContentProvider.java:1892)
   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo + 47(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:47)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider + 6391(ActivityThread.java:6391)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders + 5938(ActivityThread.java:5938)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication + 5853(ActivityThread.java:5853)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100 + 199(ActivityThread.java:199)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1650(ActivityThread.java:1650)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 106(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop + 193(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6669(ActivityThread.java:6669)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 493(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 858(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

**My Android Studio Configuration**

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26'
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 26
```

**project.properties**

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.gradle.include.1=com-sarriaroman-photoviewer/ManyTutors- 
photoviewer.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-badge/ManyTutors-badge.gradle
cordova.system.library.2=com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.0@aar
cordova.system.library.4=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+
cordova.system.library.6=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:+
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-plugin-firebase/ManyTutors-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+
cordova.system.library.9=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8
cordova.system.library.10=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+
cordova.system.library.11=com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+
cordova.system.library.12=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.4.1
cordova.system.library.13=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+
cordova.gradle.include.4=phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/ManyTutors- 
barcodescanner.gradle
```